# How can I make DNSMASQ bindings in human readable format?

Tags: bash, awk

I want to setup an alias or a script that will allow me show the DHCP bindings dnsmasq has.

```
$ cat /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases
1411349054 08:11:96:e9:52:ec 192.168.1.96 W11837894 *

1411413528 b4:b6:76:0c:c9:4d 192.168.1.46 root-HP-9470m *

1411263016 00:1b:21:0e:f2:bd 192.168.1.219 root-Dell-DM061 *

1411357237 00:01:2e:4d:49:bd 192.168.1.31 ata *

1411263041 00:30:67:d2:25:65 192.168.1.51 root-TA75M *
```

I can take the 1st column and do a date -d @1411349054 (or `awk '{print $1}' /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases | awk '{ print strftime("%c")}'`)

```
Sun Sep 21 20:24:14 CDT 2014
```

I am looking for a way in awk to format like this:

```
Sun Sep 21 20:24:14 CDT 2014 08:11:96:e9:52:ec 192.168.1.96 W11837894 *

Mon Sep 22 14:18:48 CDT 2014 b4:b6:76:0c:c9:4d 192.168.1.46 root-HP-9470m *
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Combine your current strftime command with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198138/printing-everything-except-the-first-field-with-awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below awk one-liner command,

```
awk 'NF{ $1=strftime("%c", $1);}1' file
```

**OR**

```
$ awk 'NF>1{ $1=strftime("%c", $1);}1' file
Monday 22 September 2014 06:54:14 AM IST 08:11:96:e9:52:ec 192.168.1.96 W11837894 *

Tuesday 23 September 2014 12:48:48 AM IST b4:b6:76:0c:c9:4d 192.168.1.46 root-HP-9470m *

Sunday 21 September 2014 07:00:16 AM IST 00:1b:21:0e:f2:bd 192.168.1.219 root-Dell-DM061 *

Monday 22 September 2014 09:10:37 AM IST 00:01:2e:4d:49:bd 192.168.1.31 ata *

Sunday 21 September 2014 07:00:41 AM IST 00:30:67:d2:25:65 192.168.1.51 root-TA75M *
```

Comment: THANKS so much worked like a charm.  So much can be done with gawk.

Answer (score 0):

This awk command should do the trick,

```
awk '{if ($1) {$1=strftime("%c",$1); print}}' /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases
```

Old version which would dump the Unix epoch on empty lines:

```
awk '{time=$1; $1=""; print strftime("%c",time) $0}' /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases
```

The trick is to apply `strftime` only to the relevant argument and print everything else as is. I borrowed that bit from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198138/printing-everything-except-the-first-field-with-awk).
(Since your `strftime` function worked correctly, I assume you have `gawk` installed. If not, do `sudo apt-get install gawk`.)

Comment: @AvinashRaj I've updated the answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Or  `awk '$1{ $1=strftime("%c", $1);}1' file` (but this does look quite close to gibberish). :)Thanks, that's quite a few things I've learned about awk from you today.